# ORA-00959: tablespace 'EXAMPLE' does not exist in command prompt

Tags: oracle

```
SQL> create user alois identified by alois

  2  default tablespace example password expire;

create user alois identified by alois

*
ERROR at line 1:

ORA-00959: tablespace 'EXAMPLE' does not exist
```

---

What should I do next step?

below next step like this:

```
create user alois identified by alois

default tablespace example password expire;

create user afra identified by oracle

default tablespace example quota unlimited on example;

create user anja identified by oracle;
```

Comment: Can you please try and format your question more readably? I prefer *code block*s in *fences* (`~~~`) for code/statements/instructions, and *block comments* for (machine) messages. For effective line breaks outside preformatted blocks, append two blanks to lines you want a break after.

Answer (score 1):

The tablespace `'EXAMPLE'` does not exist.
It is possible to change the user creation command and use the existing tablespace.
The USERS tablespace is almost always created.

```
create user alois identified by alois

default tablespace USERS password expire;

create user afra identified by oracle

default tablespace USERS quota unlimited on example;

create user anja identified by oracle;
```

Check Tablespace

```
select FILE_NAME,FILE_ID, TABLESPACE_NAME  from dba_data_files

/u01/oradata/DEV/system01.dbf       1   SYSTEM
/u01/oradata/DEV/sysaux01.dbf       3   SYSAUX
/u01/oradata/DEV/undotbs01.dbf      4   UNDOTBS1
/u01/oradata/DEV/users01.dbf        7   USERS
/u01/oradata/DEV/users_ind01.dbf    5   USERS_IND

 select a.tablespace_name , 
        round(a.used_space*8192/(1024*1024*1024),2) as USED_GB, 
        round(a.tablespace_size*8192/(1024*1024*1024),2) as  MAX_SIZE_GB, 
        round(a.used_percent ,2) as USED_PERCENT 
   from dba_tablespace_usage_metrics a


TABLESPACE_NAME  USED_GB  MAX_SIZE_GB  USED_PERCENT       
-------------- ------ -------------- ---------
SYSAUX        6,9         32        21,58
SYSTEM        1,11        32        3,48
TEMP          0           32        0,01
UNDOTBS1      0,04        32        0,14
USERS         23,06       32        72,07
USERS_IND     11,04       32        34,49
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `EXAMPLE` tablespace doesn't exist; you need to create it before you can assign it to a user as a default. It can be created with the `CREATE TABLESPACE` command.

Precise syntax will depend on your storage type, datafile naming conventions, etc. See here for details: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLESPACE.html#GUID-51F07BF5-EFAF-4910-9040-C473B86A8BF9

You may need to check with your DBA and have them do this, or provide you with the name of an existing tablespace you can use instead.